# How to install access BIOS with broken screen

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, multiple-monitors, bios

I have Sony vaio laptop(svf15213snb) around 9 year old. Laptop was completely fine when screen broke and used laptop on external monitor for some time and completely detached internal screen and bazel. Sometime later i formatted its HDD and used somewhere else.

Now i want to use it again but to install any OS on this laptop, i must get into BIOS but can't access BIOS on external display.

- I tried to put magnet near hall sensor to trick computer think lead
  closed and return bios screen on external monitor but didn't work.
- Also tried to plug bootable USB if anything comes up on screen but no
  luck. I'm not sure what to do.

I heard somewhere that Linux can be easily migrate on other machine!! I didn't try this one.

Comment: So what's your goal? Accessing the BIOS? Getting Linux to install?

Comment: Yes, getting laptop on.

Comment: Are you using legacy or UEFI boot?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a separate F-key to change boot-order *only*, without entering BIOS/UEFI, that would be a better option when working blind. Some makers, e.g., HP and Toshiba, use <kbd>F9</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>, to enter that limited-option screen.

Try booting with a single <kbd>Down</kbd> push, and if that doesn't work try with two or three. You can make a bootable USB device, e.g. [Ubuntu Desktop Live](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview), once you find the USB boot option, this should load in "user test" mode by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after boot-up finishes. Usually, Ubuntu installation media can boot in EFI or in Legacy mode, so you should not need to make a switch in BIOS.

Hopefully, Ubuntu will recognize that a display is connected!